# $(X_n)$ an irreducible transient Markov chain. Is $f(x) = \mathbb{P}(X_n = x_0 \text{ for some } n > 0 | X_0=x)$ constant?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

Let $(X_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be an irreducible transient Markov chain with countably infinite state space $E$. Let $T_x = \inf\{n > 0 : X_n = x\}$. Let $\mathbb{P}_x$ be probability conditioned on $X_0 = x$.

Then $0 < \mathbb{P}_x(T_x < \infty) < 1$ for all $x \in E$ and $\mathbb{P}_x(T_y < \infty) > 0$ for all $x,y \in E$.

Fix $x_0 \in E$ and set $f(x) = \mathbb{P}_x(T_{x_0} < \infty)$. Is it true that $f$ is non-constant?

If $f$ is constant, then 
$$
f(x) = \mathbb{P}_x(T_{x_0} < \infty) = \mathbb{P}_{x_0}(T_{x_0} < \infty) = f(x_0)
$$
for all $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I've changed my answer to give a stronger result. I do not assume that the chain is irreducible, that $f$ is constant, or that the state space is infinite. The argument below shows that if there is a transient state $x_0$, then the chance of hitting $x_0$ can be made arbitrarily small by starting "far away" from $x_0$.

---

Let $\alpha=\inf_x f(x)$. Then for all $n\geq 0$:
$$\mathbb{P}_{x_0}(T_{x_0}\circ\theta_n<\infty)=(P^n f)(x_0)\geq \alpha,$$ 
where the left hand side is the chance of hitting state $x_0$ after time $n$. 
If the state $x_0$ is transient, letting $n\to\infty$ gives
$$ 0=\mathbb{P}_{x_0}(X_n=x_0\mbox{ infinitely often }) = \lim_n \mathbb{P}_{x_0}(T_{x_0}\circ\theta_n<\infty)\geq \alpha.$$ Therefore, $\inf_x f(x)=0$.

Comment: I don't understand the first equation. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @RClark I've changed my answer. What part don't you understand?

Comment: I'm actually having trouble unravelling the equality in the first displayed equation.

Comment: RClark Do you know this notation: for example $\theta_n$ and $P^n$?

Comment: I figured it out. It was a matter of unwrapping the notation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is non-constant.  For example, consider biased random walk on the integers (say step to the left with probability $p < 1/2$, to the right with $1-p$).  Then ${\mathbb P}_x(T_{x_0} < \infty) = 1$ if $x < x_0$ but $\to 0$ as $x \to +\infty$.

Comment: I don't see why it should be non-constant for an arbitrary irreducible transient Markov chain.